# Factorisation of a map of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose you have a ring $A$, $B$ with and an $A$-module $M$. Suppose the projection $q:A\rightarrow B$ is surjective, and that there's a map $f:A\rightarrow M$. Under what assumptions and why does $f$ factor through a map $B\rightarrow M$? 
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{lllllll}
A & \ra{f} & M \\
\da{q} & &  \\
B & \\
\end{array}
$$
Sorry for the shitty diagram, but basically the question is when is there a unique arrow from $B$ to $M$ that makes the diagram commute.

Comment: What is $q$ exactly?  A ring homomorphism?  And what is $B$?

Comment: Yes. You can take even B to be just a quotient ring A/I with I an ideal of A